# Problems with Markers and Clusters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Based on json data I need to populate a map with markers.
If makers are too close, they group into a cluster.
I'm using these extensions for Markers and Clusters:(https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries)

I wrote the following code that is accomplishing what I need, except with a few issues:

1 - It looks like it is stacking markers and clusters. If I use chrome inspector and remove a cluster or a marker, there's another one right under. As I zoom in or drag the map, it seems that it stacks even more.

2 - When zooming out, some markers still show outside the cluster and the number showing in the cluster is already counting it. This seems to be related to the stacking as mentioned in the previous point.

Here's the main parts of my code:

```
function initialize(lat, lng) {
    window.lat = lat;
    window.lng =lng;
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 13,
      maxZoom:18,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true
   };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-full'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        $mapBounds = map.getBounds();
        getJSONData($mapBounds);
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(<?=$location;?>));

function getJSONData(map_bounds){
    var bounds  = {
        'swlat':map_bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        'swlng':map_bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
        'nelat':map_bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        'nelng':map_bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
    };

    data = {
        'bounds': bounds,
    }

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "<?=$data_URL;?>",
    data: data,
    success: function (json) {
        populateMap(json, bounds);
    }
    });
}    

function populateMap(data, bounds){

//// ADD Markers
    var markerCluster = null;
    var markers = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    leftList(data); // adds properties to left list
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);  
        // drop the marker
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            labelContent: data[i].price,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(27, 35),
            title: data[i].title,
            labelClass: "map-markers",
            infoData: data[i],
            zIndex: i

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            var info_content = makeMarkerInfo(this.infoData, this.index);
            infowindow.setContent(info_content);
            infowindow.open(map,this);

        });

        markers.push(marker);

    }

///// ADD CLUSTERS
    var clusterOptions = {
        zoomOnClick: false
    }

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

    // Zoom in or show infowindow when click on Cluster
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
        if (map.getZoom() < map.maxZoom ){        
            map.setCenter(cluster.center_);
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 4);
        } else {

            var content = '';
            // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
            var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
            info.set('position', cluster.center_);
            //Get markers
            var marks_in_cluster = cluster.getMarkers();

            console.log(marks_in_cluster);

            for (var z = 0; z < marks_in_cluster.length; z++) {
                content = makeClusterInfo(marks_in_cluster,z) ;
            }
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setContent(content); 
            infowindow.open(map, info);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                infowindow.close()
            });
        } 
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe everytime the map triggers the idle (This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming. see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en)), you simply duplicate the markers. Before adding new markers on the map, you should CLEAR those markers by looping throught the markers array and setting the map to NULL.

```
var i = 0;
var total = markers.length;
for (; i<total; i++) {
 markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Then you REBUILD EVERYTHING. Clusterer changed at this point. So put your call to the clusterer in a function, and call it back everytime the markers array changes. This should do it!

Hope that helps

EDIT: Here's a little rewrite of the code. This is NOT optimal, but look at it and try to figure out what I did and why. Added some comments to explain. THIS IS NOT TESTED

Here it is:

```
// I guess you have this at some point in your code
var map;

/**
 * Init function
 * @param  {float} lat Latitude
 * @param  {float} lng Longitude
 */
function initialize(lat, lng) {
    window.lat = lat;
    window.lng =lng;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 13,
      maxZoom:18,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-full'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        $mapBounds = map.getBounds();
        getJSONData($mapBounds);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(<?=$location;?>));

/**
 * Gets the json data for the map
 * @param  {array} map_bounds Boundaries of the google map after idle
 */
function getJSONData(map_bounds){
    var bounds  = {
        'swlat':map_bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        'swlng':map_bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
        'nelat':map_bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        'nelng':map_bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
    };

    data = {
        'bounds': bounds,
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "<?=$data_URL;?>",
        data: data,
        success: function (json) {
            populateMap(json, bounds);
        }
    });
}

// Keep track of the markers and clusterer
var markers;
var markerCluster;

/**
 * Create the map with the datas
 * @param  {json} data    Map data
 * @param  {array} bounds Map boundaries
 */
function populateMap(data, bounds){

    // Assume you can clear markers and clusterer
    // If they exist at this point
    if (markers.length) {
        var i = 0;
        var total = markers.length;
        for (; i<total; i++) {
            // Remove click listeners
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(markers[i], 'click');
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }

    // Start over
    markers = [];

    if (markerCluster) {
        // Remove click listeners
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(markerCluster, 'clusterclick');
        markerCluster.setMap(null);
    }

    // Start over
    markerCluster = null;

    // @NOTE
    // THE REST IS UNCHECK FROM HERE
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    leftList(data); // adds properties to left list
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);  
        // drop the marker
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            labelContent: data[i].price,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(27, 35),
            title: data[i].title,
            labelClass: "map-markers",
            infoData: data[i],
            zIndex: i

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            var info_content = makeMarkerInfo(this.infoData, this.index);
            infowindow.setContent(info_content);
            infowindow.open(map,this);

        });

        markers.push(marker);

    }

    ///// ADD CLUSTERS
    var clusterOptions = {
        zoomOnClick: false
    }

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

    // Zoom in or show infowindow when click on Cluster
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
        if (map.getZoom() < map.maxZoom ){
            map.setCenter(cluster.center_);
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 4);
        } else {

            var content = '';
            // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
            var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
            info.set('position', cluster.center_);
            //Get markers
            var marks_in_cluster = cluster.getMarkers();

            console.log(marks_in_cluster);

            for (var z = 0; z < marks_in_cluster.length; z++) {
                content = makeClusterInfo(marks_in_cluster,z) ;
            }
            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, info);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                infowindow.close()
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: That was the impression that I was getting. However, with the current functions structure, I'm not sure where to place your code to clear the markers, mainly because how do I get the current markers before refreshing with new markers?

I think I'll have to structure the functions in a different way.

Comment: Added rewritten code to help you understand all of this!

Comment: I actually solved in a different way.
I realize that the MarkerClusterer does the job to populate the map with markers, so adding markers before defining the clusterer will result on duplication of the markers. 
So, the solution passes by adding the markers to the array to pass on the the cluster as it was already doing, but now without defining the map for the marker. The clusterer will then populate the map with markers and clusters. 
Clearing the clusters before populating is also needed. 
I'll be posting my solution. 
Thanks for your answer, anyway it really helped to find the problems.